# how to make a view controller observer in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, observers

I have made my list (array of MarketIndex objects) as an observable with the help of this website:

http://www.drewag.me/posts/swift-kvo-substitute-observable-variables

This is the code of Observable from the above website that I have added to my program:

```
    import Foundation


class Observable: NSObject {

    typealias DidChangeHandler = (oldValue: Array<MarketIndex>?, newValue: Array<MarketIndex>) -> ()

    dynamic var value : Array<MarketIndex> {
        didSet {
            for (owner, handlers) in self.observers {
                for handler in handlers {
                    handler(oldValue: oldValue, newValue: value)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    init(_ value: Array<MarketIndex>) {
        self.value = value
        super.init()
    }

    func addObserverForOwner(owner: AnyObject, triggerImmediately: Bool, handler: DidChangeHandler) {

        if let index = self.indexOfOwner(owner) {
            // since the owner exists, add the handler to the existing array
            self.observers[index].handlers.append(handler)
        } else {
            // since the owner does not already exist, add a new tuple with the
            // owner and an array with the handler
            self.observers.append(owner: owner, handlers: [handler])
        }

        if (triggerImmediately) {
            // Trigger the handler immediately since it was requested
            handler(oldValue: nil, newValue: self.value)
        }
    }

    func removeObserversForOwner(owner: AnyObject) {
        if let index = self.indexOfOwner(owner) {
            self.observers.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }

    // #pragma mark - Private Properties

    var observers: [(owner: AnyObject, handlers: [DidChangeHandler])] = []

    // #pragma mark - Private Methods

    func indexOfOwner(owner: AnyObject) -> Int? {
        var index : Int = 0
        for (possibleOwner, handlers) in self.observers {
            if possibleOwner === owner {
                return index
            }
            index++
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And here is the code of SocketManager that has the list of MarketIndex objects which will become observable.

```
    import Foundation

class SocketManager: WebSocketDelegate {

    class var sharedInstance: SocketManager {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: SocketManager? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = SocketManager()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
    var marketIndexList: Array<MarketIndex> = []
    var indexesList: Observable = Observable([])

    init() {

    }

    func getMarketIndexes(inputStream: String) {

            // the marketIndexList will be updated from server every time that a value changes in the server

            indexesList = Observable(marketIndexList)

            println("\(indexesList.value)")
        }

        println("Market Index List Size: \(indexesList.value.count)")
    }
}
```

Now, I want to make my ViewController an observer for this list. 
I have added the function addObserverForOwner in the function viewDidLoad() but it doesn't change every time my list changes. 
Here is the code of my ViewController:

SocketManager is the class that has the indexesList which is observable. Also, SocketManager is Singleton. notify() function will update the values of labels and reload the tableView of my ViewController.

```
    class IndexViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()    
    SocketManager.sharedInstance.indexesList.addObserverForOwner(self, triggerImmediately: true) { (oldValue, newValue) -> () in

                self.marketIndexes = newValue
                self.notify()
            }
    }

func notify() {

        updateValues(marketIndexes)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong in here? Any ideas?

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an `Observable` object, `indexesList`, which has an `init` method that looks like:

```
init(_ value: Array<MarketIndex>) {
    self.value = value
    super.init()
}
```

But note that `Array` is a `struct`, so `self.value` gets a copy of whatever you pass to it. So the `didSet` logic will not be called when `marketIndexes` updates, but rather only when the local copy of `value` within `indexesList` is updated (i.e. never).

There are other issues with this code sample (I don't see where you call `getMarketIndexes`; if you did call it, it re-instantiates the the Observable object, discarding the old array of closures; you want to be careful about using `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]` in your closures; etc.), but I'm not sure we have to worry about them. The critical issue to tackle first is that if you want to use this pattern from that other site, one would retire `indexesList`, and employ that pattern to `marketIndexes` itself.

In my mind, this seriously diminishes the value of the `Observable` class. This is not a general mechanism that can be applied to existing classes/properties, but rather it is a pattern you have to re-implement for every property to which you want to add observers. You certainly can do that, and it works, but it feels a bit heavy.

Frankly, given that `marketIndexes` is member of the view controller, itself, I would think long and hard about why you don't just do something far more direct:

```
var marketIndexList: [MarketIndex] = [] {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

You would probably only employ that "array of closures to be called by `didSet`" pattern if the object that you were observing was in a different class (i.e. the class with `marketIndexList` has no way of knowing how many observers there will be, nor what particularly the observers will want to do). And, even then, I'd personally think long and hard about whether I want my own observation mechanism rather than existing, well-established patterns (notifications, KVO/KVN, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Rob. But the `marketIndexes` does not get updated every time my array updated from the other class. So, I cannot use the didSet and reload the table in it. My problem is how to get my `marketIndexes` updated in my ViewController when ever the array in the other class (SocketManager) got updated.
Also, I called my method `getMarketIndexes` in the method that received the message from the socket. So, every time a new message receives, I call the `getMarketIndexes` and update my array and make it Observable.

Comment: No, your code isn't going to work at all. You seem to be operating under the assumption that you can employ this Observable pattern on the `indexesList` variable, and some how changes in `marketIndexList` will translate to observer messages managed by `indexesList`. That's not going to work. You have to employ this pattern on the `marketIndexList` variable itself if you want this to work. Retire that `indexesList` variable altogether.

Comment: At first, that was the thing I wanted to do. I wanted to make the marketIndexList as an observable with the above Observable class but it didn't work out. I wrote `marketIndexList = Observable(marketIndexList)` but i got an error that said: 'MarketIndex' is not identical to 'AnyObject'

Comment: You keep acting like you can have this independent `Observable` class. To use this technique, you make `marketIndexList` whatever you want (e.g. your `Array`), and then implement the `addObserverForOwner`, `removeObservers`, and `indexOfOwner` in the class that has this object, and have those methods that reference `marketIndexList`. This technique advised by this article you reference is really quite clumsy and is a poor replacement for standard notification mechanisms, IMHO. But do whatever you want.

Comment: @user2366997 If you wanted to have the socket class have an observer for `marketIndexList`, you could do something like https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/e2a5307fd17fa9673017